# AngularJs ng-click $event passes child element as target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

For each *td* element in a table I have an attached ng-click. Here is the (simplified) html for each table cell:

```
<td ng-click="cellClicked($event)">
    <span ng-if="!cellEdit">{{event.eventName}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-if="cellEdit" ng-model="event.eventName">
</td>
```

And my (simplified) ng-click function:

```
scope.cellClicked = function (event) {
  rowScope.cellEdit = true
  angular.element(event.target).find('input').focus()
}
```

Its my goal to:

1. User clicks a table cell
2. Cell changes to "edit mode"
3. Give focus to the *input* element located inside the *td*.

Right now this is working as long as the user clicks **inside the td element but not on the span element**:

```
console.log(angular.element(event.target)) #--> [td...] (as desired)
```

However if the user clicks on the span element within the td:

```
console.log(angular.element(event.target)) #--> [span...]
```

In this use case assigning focus does not work. I was hoping to access the parent element of the *span* doing something like:

```
angular.element(event.target.closest('td'))
```

or

```
angular.element(event.target.parentNode)
```

But it appears when an element gets passed through via $event and accessed there is no parent context.

How can I either:

- Prevent clicking the *span* element firing the *td*'s ng-click
- On click of *span* element pass through it's html parent

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Changing:

```
angular.element(event.target)
```

to:

```
angular.element(event.currentTarget)
```

fixed my issue.

It seems to me using [event.currentTarget](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp) is preferred to [event.target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) in the majority of usage cases.

Answer (score 3):

`event.target.closest('td')` won't work because `event.target` is a DOM element and it doesn't have method `closest`. You need to create a jQuery object to use this method.

Try to find closest `td` like this:

```
angular.element(event.target).closest('td')
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. Trying this gives: [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div.ng-scope.ng-binding, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: ""…]

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work, I mean what you posted is a jQuery object. Does it selects parent TD?

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work. You're right, it is a jQuery object, but not the one I want. Something like [td ....] is what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 7.x

```
myClickHandler($event) {
    this.selectedElement = <Element>$event.target.closest('.list-item');
}
```

html:

```
<div class="list-item" (click)="myClickHandler($event)">...</div>
```