# How to get "this" background image's url using "$event.target" to show in ionic modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, dom-events

How to show clicked image in modal

**In view:**

```
<a ng-click="openModal($event)" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/img/img-01.jpg)'}"><img src="assets/alpha-4x3.png"></a>
<a ng-click="openModal($event)" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/img/img-02.jpg)'}"><img src="assets/alpha-4x3.png"></a>
```

**In controller:**

```
 $scope.openModal = function($event) {
   $scope.modal.show();
   $scope.poppedUpImg = $event.target.style.backgroundImage;
 };
```

**In Modal Template:**

```
<ion-content class="p20">
  <img ng-src="{{poppedUpImg}}" src="" alt="">
</ion-content>
```

Image not able to make the above code work. Or please suggest the better way to do it. The alpha image is taking my clicks.

**Edit/Update**

@Sphinxxx answer worked if the anchor is holding text content, if there is image inside the anchor then his answer does not work. Here is what I did to make things work.

```
$event.srcElement.parentElement.style.backgroundImage.split('("')[1].split('")'‌​)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I'm guessing `$event.target.style.backgroundImage` is `"url(assets/img/...)"`. To make a proper image `src`, you need to extract the url between the parentheses:

```
$scope.poppedUpImg = $event.target.style.backgroundImage
                                        .split('("')[1]
                                        .split('")')[0];
```

**Edit:**

If the clicked `<a>` contains child elements, `$event.target` will be the clicked child element. To always access the `<a>` element, use `$event.currentTarget` instead ([Angular ng-click $event passes child element as target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421360/angular-ng-click-event-passes-child-element-as-target)).

Example (click either the small "contained" thumbs or the larger backgrounds):
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26551/

Comment: getting this error `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: actually that worked. the problem is I mentioned above that I was placing "Some text" actually I was placing some transparent in all DIVs `<img src="assets/img/alfa-4x3.png">` when I changed with some text then your code worked. To have a image and to make it work as I needed I coded this way `$event.srcElement.parentElement.style.backgroundImage.split('("')[1].split('")')[0]`

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above if there is image inside the anchor then your answer does not work for me. Hopefully there is better way than I did :) not sure.

Comment: You're right. `$event.target` causes problems when there are child elements inside the anchor. I've added an example with a more fail-safe solution.